# Precision of LinearModelFit with Polynomials

Tags: fitting, polynomials, machine-precision

I have a Problem regarding the fit of given points with a polynomial up to the fifth degree.

```
 tableofvalues=Import["tableofvalues.csv"]
```

My polynomial is:

```
polynomtabelle={1, x[1], x[1]^2, x[1]^3, x[1]^4, x[1]^5, x[2], x[2]^2, x[2]^3, x[2]^4, x[2]^5, x[3], x[3]^2, x[3]^3, x[3]^4, x[3]^5, x[4], x[4]^2,  x[4]^3, x[4]^4, x[4]^5}

polynom = LinearModelFit[tableofvalues, polynomtabelle,  Array[x, {4}]];
```

I know that my points have a certain symmetry. So the linear factors of coordinate x[1] have to be the same as for x[4]. The same applies for x[2] and x[3]. But if I ask for the coefficients I get for example:

```
NumberForm[Extract[CoefficientList[polynom["BestFit"], Array[x, {4}]], {5, 0, 0, 0} + 1], Floor@$MachinePrecision]
0.0619247206844402

NumberForm[Extract[CoefficientList[polynom["BestFit"], Array[x, {4}]], {0, 0, 0, 5} + 1], Floor@$MachinePrecision]
0.0619247173030426
```

One sees that they differ in the eigth digit after the decimal point, which is an accuracy too low for later treatment of the polynomial. Especially we have an old fitting routine written in FORTRAN in our working group that achieves 0.0619247173 for both coefficients. (Infact I intended to replace it with this one written in Mathematica).

How can I achieve numerically a better result. Perhaps you will ask for the precision of my input.

```
Precision[tableofvalues]
MachinePrecision
```

I run Mathematica on a 64Bit Computer so

```
$MachinePrecision
15.9546
```

The tableofvalues.csv is:

0.,0.,0.,0.,-0.9084906825

-0.04724315325,0.,0.,0.,-0.9075435543

-0.0377945226,0.,0.,0.,-0.9078643076

-0.028345891949999997,0.,0.,0.,-0.9081173929

-0.0188972613,0.,0.,0.,-0.9083049166

-0.00944863065,0.,0.,0.,-0.9084286871

0.00944863065,0.,0.,0.,-0.908492608

0.0188972613,0.,0.,0.,-0.9084363935

0.028345891949999997,0.,0.,0.,-0.9083237119

0.0377945226,0.,0.,0.,-0.9081562202

0.04724315325,0.,0.,0.,-0.9079356124

0.,-0.04724315325,0.,0.,-0.9074790503

0.,-0.0377945226,0.,0.,-0.9078199288

0.,-0.028345891949999997,0.,0.,-0.9080895811

0.,-0.0188972613,0.,0.,-0.9082900218

0.,-0.00944863065,0.,0.,-0.9084230317

0.,0.00944863065,0.,0.,-0.9084947071

0.,0.0188972613,0.,0.,-0.9084370745

0.,0.028345891949999997,0.,0.,-0.9083194184

0.,0.0377945226,0.,0.,-0.9081434864

0.,0.04724315325,0.,0.,-0.9079110427

0.,0.,-0.04724315325,0.,-0.9074790503

0.,0.,-0.0377945226,0.,-0.9078199288

0.,0.,-0.028345891949999997,0.,-0.9080895811

0.,0.,-0.0188972613,0.,-0.9082900218

0.,0.,-0.00944863065,0.,-0.9084230317

0.,0.,0.00944863065,0.,-0.9084947071

0.,0.,0.0188972613,0.,-0.9084370745

0.,0.,0.028345891949999997,0.,-0.9083194184

0.,0.,0.0377945226,0.,-0.9081434864

0.,0.,0.04724315325,0.,-0.9079110427

0.,0.,0.,-0.04724315325,-0.9075435543

0.,0.,0.,-0.0377945226,-0.9078643076

0.,0.,0.,-0.028345891949999997,-0.9081173929

0.,0.,0.,-0.0188972613,-0.9083049166

0.,0.,0.,-0.00944863065,-0.9084286871

0.,0.,0.,0.00944863065,-0.908492608

0.,0.,0.,0.0188972613,-0.9084363935

0.,0.,0.,0.028345891949999997,-0.9083237119

0.,0.,0.,0.0377945226,-0.9081562202

0.,0.,0.,0.04724315325,-0.9079356124

Comment: Just curious: Adding degrees of freedom artificially will make your results worse. If you already know that the model's coefficients have a certain relationship, why don't you state that right in the model?

Comment: I made this table as minimal example. But I also need coupling constants lateron. For example the linear factor a*x[1]*x[4]. So it's not possible to just skipt x[3] and x[4] and mirror x[1] and x[2] onto them. 
For the diagonal elements this was of course possible.

Comment: Beside from this I would like to understand where this decrease of precision of 8 orders of magnitude comes from.

Comment: Using your data, the results from your `NumberForm[ ]` in my machine are more like `6.39247197093749` ....

Comment: Unfortunately I can't help you in pinpointing the origin of the drop in precision, but it seems that you can get what you want by manually setting your input values to an arbitrary (high) precision: `tableofvalues = SetPrecision[#, 40]& @ {yourdata}`. You will then obtain coefficients from your expression that are numerically the same to within the precision you have set. Further note: I also get the 6.39... answers from your code that @belisarius reported.

Comment: I got the same problem whit the 6.39247197093749 when i copied from the website. It works if it is read from a CSV file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**UPDATE**

A more accurate explanation than the culprit being "low variability" is that because all of the dependent variable values begin with "-0.907" or "-0.908" essentially "eats up"/"wastes" the first 3 significant digits.  Simply subtracting the minimimum value of the dependent variable works even better than standardizing by the mean and standard deviation:

```
`(* Subtract minimum value from the dependent variable *)
tableofvalues[[All, 5]] = tableofvalues[[All, 5]] - Min[tableofvalues[[All, 5]]];`
```

The resulting values of the two coefficients in question become

```
0.0619247172727312
0.0619247172719015
```

This is a very common issue that can produce odd results for nearly all statistical packages.  Looking intensely at the data and using some form of standardization is always recommended.

**End of UPDATE**

The main culprit is the low variability of the dependent variable:  `tableofvalues[[All,5]]`.  If you standardize that variable (subtracting the mean and then dividing by the standard deviation), then all your troubles go away.  In fact standardizing variables is almost always recommended even for the independent variables whenever there might be round-off error involved especially for the fitting of polynomials.  However, the suggestion by @MarcoB (setting a higher precision) achieves essentially the same result.

```
stdvalues = tableofvalues;
stdvalues[[All, 5]] = Standardize[tableofvalues[[All, 5]]];
stdev5 = StandardDeviation[tableofvalues[[All, 5]]];

polynomtabelle = {1, x[1], x[1]^2, x[1]^3, x[1]^4, x[1]^5, x[2], 
  x[2]^2, x[2]^3, x[2]^4, x[2]^5, x[3], x[3]^2, x[3]^3, x[3]^4, 
  x[3]^5, x[4], x[4]^2, x[4]^3, x[4]^4, x[4]^5}

polynom = LinearModelFit[stdvalues, polynomtabelle, Array[x, {4}]];

NumberForm[
 stdev5 Extract[
   CoefficientList[polynom["BestFit"], Array[x, {4}]], {5, 0, 0, 0} + 
    1], Floor@$MachinePrecision]

NumberForm[
 stdev5 Extract[
   CoefficientList[polynom["BestFit"], Array[x, {4}]], {0, 0, 0, 5} + 
    1], Floor@$MachinePrecision]
```

with output

```
(* 0.0619247172791471 *)
(* 0.0619247172736994 *)
```

Note that one must multiply by the standard deviation of `tableofvalues[[All,5]]` to get the appropriate coefficient.

Comment: Thank you very much! 

If I apply the solution of @MarcoB, I got some interesting behaviour.
With
tableofvalues = 
 SetPrecision[#,Floor@ MachinePrecision] &@Import["tableofvalues.csv"];
everything works fine
BUT if I use SetPrecision[#,MachinePrecision] the problem with different values of symmetrical terms arises.

Comment: If I replace the top 3 lines of the standardization code above with `stdvalues = Flatten[SetPrecision[#, 40] &@{tableofvalues}, 1];`, then I get (after removing the multiplication by `stdev5`) both results being `0.0619247172725849`.  So that is likely a better result than doing the standardization that I suggested.

Comment: I'd also like to suggest that fitting 21 coefficients with 41 data points, seems a bit excessive not to mention the use of a 5th degree polynomial for all independent variables.  And from your comments it sounds like you're about to include additional interaction terms.  You might consider using something like AIC to decide when overfitting becomes a problem.

Comment: I wanted to avoid SetPrecision[#, 40] &@{tableofvalues} or any other arbitrary precision number to prevent numerically inefficient code. And the precision using Floor@$MachinePrecision is sufficient now. So my actual problem is solved. BUT again, the behaviour of SetPrecision is really strange. I get good results for every Integer number and hence also for Floor@MachinePrecision and Round@MachinePrecision. But as soon as I use SetPrecision[@,MachinePrecision] symmetrical terms differ in the eigth digit after decimal point.

Comment: This can be reproduced with the data given. @Jim Baldwin the tableofvalues posted is just a minimal example. Infact I use 361 points and 73 degrees of freedom.

Comment: Subtracting the minimum value from the dependent variable removes the issue with using SetPrecision[@,MachinePrecision].  Unless you need to run such models hundred or thousands of times, I wouldn't worry about numerically inefficient code.  But then again I'm more biased towards readable code which is always a challenge for me using Mathematica.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24731/discussion-between-jim-baldwin-and-mcocdawc).